# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. exit code: 1

Tags: python, pip

Tried to download the package `feature_selector`.
Introduced `pip install feature_selector`
And got this error:

```
Collecting feature_selector
  Using cached feature_selector-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting seaborn==0.8.1
  Using cached seaborn-0.8.1.tar.gz (178 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pandas==0.23.1
  Using cached pandas-0.23.1.tar.gz (13.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting scikit-learn==0.19.1
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.19.1.tar.gz (9.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting lightgbm==2.1.1
  Using cached lightgbm-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (711 kB)
Collecting matplotlib==2.1.2
  Using cached matplotlib-2.1.2.tar.gz (36.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [71 lines of output]
      IMPORTANT WARNING:
          pkg-config is not installed.
          matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
      ============================================================================
      Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

      BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                  matplotlib: yes [2.1.2]
                      python: yes [3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08)  [GCC
                              9.4.0]]
                    platform: yes [linux]

      REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                       numpy: yes [version 1.22.2]
                         six: yes [using six version 1.16.0]
                    dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.8.2]
      backports.functools_lru_cache: yes [Not required]
                subprocess32: yes [Not required]
                        pytz: yes [using pytz version 2021.3]
                      cycler: yes [using cycler version 0.10.0]
                     tornado: yes [using tornado version 6.1]
                   pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 3.0.7]
                      libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                              be found. Using local copy.]
                    freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                              could not be found.  You may need to install the
                              development package.]
                         png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                              be found.]
                       qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                              be found. Using local copy.]

      OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
                 sample_data: yes [installing]
                    toolkits: yes [installing]
                       tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
              toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

      OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                      macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                      qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                      qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                     gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-r4l4iwft/matplotlib_dc4d5c9010ec47f683a393a9a7c83d4f/setup.py", line 216, in <module>
          pkg_help = pkg.install_help_msg()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-r4l4iwft/matplotlib_dc4d5c9010ec47f683a393a9a7c83d4f/setupext.py", line 595, in install_help_msg
          release = platform.linux_distribution()[0].lower()
      AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'
                   gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                      gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                              Tk]
                       wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                         gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                         agg: yes [installing]
                       cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                   windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

      OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                      dvipng: no
                 ghostscript: no
                       latex: no
                     pdftops: no

      OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                        dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

      ============================================================================
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Can you try to `apt install pkg-configure` and then retry?

Comment: Tried got the same error

Comment: It still said `pkg-config is not installed.` even after you installed it?

Comment: ```error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [68 lines of output]
      ============================================================================
      Edit setup.cfg to change the build options```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked through all the existing suggestions - I found I had to `pip install Cython`
(Windows)  (eg I had updated pip, ez_setup, setuptools, mysqlclient, flask-mysqldb  and more with no joy)